# Is 270ml of coffee in a 6-cup Bialetti Moka attainable with the correct grind size?

Tags: brewing-process, moka, grind-size

I have just bought a 6-cup Bialetti Moka Express, and the user manual quotes its 300 ml reservoir should result in 270 ml of coffee.
However, I have conducted some tests, and unless the grind size is around kosher salt, I am unable to get more than 100 ml out of it. I control the heat to have a stable flow. When the bubbles start I remove the heat and cool the pot down with cold water.

Does extracting so little coffee when compared to the manual quoted figure an indication anything is wrong?
If so, could you point where the problem might be coming from?

Comment: Are you measuring the water that you put in the bottom chamber? Is the bottom chamber mostly empty after brewing? Have you tried just taking the Moka off the stove once it’s starts gargling?

Comment: @Stephie Yes, I put water just below the pressure release valve, that holds about 270ml. So yes, there is still a good amount of water inside of the Moka after brewing. I take the Moka off the stove and cool it with cold water after it starts gargling.

Comment: try to put a bit less water in it, pre heated. paradoxically, that may lead to more yield. use boiling water, don't tamp the coffee, reduce heat as soon as the liquid starts to emerge to get a slow flow.